# How to convert given SQL query to Eloquent laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am bit struggling to convert below given SQL query to eloquent.

Here is an example of what I am trying to do -

```
SELECT u.wallet_address AS wallet_address, p.id AS project_id
FROM users u, projects p, investment_investor i
WHERE u.id = i.user_id AND 
      p.id=i.project_id AND 
      u.wallet_address <> '' AND 
      p.wallet_address <> '' AND
      p.contract_address <> ''
GROUP BY u.id, p.id;
```

The below SQL query gives me the expected output, which I am able to build with the Laravel DB query builder. But want to standardise it to Laravel framework.

Your help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

First thing you need to have to be able to write queries in the laravel way is something called `Model`. Example of a model would be like so

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Flight extends Model
{
    //
}
```

You can read more about it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#defining-models)

Once you create it, you can start writing queries. For example

```
$results = Users::selectRaw('users.wallet_address as `wallet_address`,'.
                 'id as `project_id`')
                ->get();
```

You can read more about joins and other things [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#basic-usage)

Comment: I already have my DB query builder snippet running well. I am looking for a way to write eloquent query for the above given example.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $result=DB::table('investment_investor')
    ->select('users.wallet_address as wallet_address','projects.id AS project_id')
    ->join('users','users.id','=','investment_investor.user_id')
    ->join('projects','projects.id','=','investment_investor.project_id')
    ->where('users.wallet_address','!=','')
    ->where('projects.wallet_address','!=','')
    ->where('projects.contract_address','!=,'')
    ->groupBy('users.id', 'projects.id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Thanks @jithesh, the same query I already have.. It is with DB builder, which I am not looking for.. I am looking for Model relations eloquent query.